# Does JTextField have a getEditor() method?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield, keylistener

I search for an answer to my problem but nothing helps. Here is my code:

```
jtf = new JTextField(15);
jtf.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() 
{
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt)
    {
        if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
        {
            jb.doClick();
        }
    }
});
```

How can I trigger JButton when pressing enter in a JTextField or panel or whatever else?

edit: solved!

```
private class ListenForButton implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source == jb2) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else if (source == jb) {
            ..
        } else { 
          ..
        }
        }
        catch (SQLException | HeadlessException a) {
            ..
        }
        } else if (source == jtf) // its work now
        {
            jb.doClick();
        }
    }
```

Comment: no `JTextField` doesn't have such a method.you can use keypress event for that.you could use Key Bindings

Comment: According to the docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html the action listener responds to enter keypress events. Im assuming you found that when you searched for your problem though. Is there a reason that doesnt work for you?

Comment: @FastSnail key bindings more effective thank you

Comment: @JasonC thank you too for reminding. i searched one more time and i found whats wrong my code i'll edit my question solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you give us more context?

I tried adding a enter listener on the text field and it seems to be working just fine, here is my code.

```
package com.apixandru.jvshot;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import static java.awt.BorderLayout.EAST;
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog;

/**
 * @author Alexandru-Constantin Bledea
 * @since Sep 12, 2016
 */
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JButton jb = new JButton("Search");
        jb.addActionListener((evt) -> showMessageDialog(null, "Button 'clicked'"));

        JTextField jtf = new JTextField(15);
        jtf.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
                if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    jb.doClick();
                }
            }
        });

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(jtf);
        panel.add(jb, EAST);
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: I mean you could just use an ActionListener too instead of the KeyListener. In fact you can even just use the same listener for both the button and the text field, which might semantically make more sense anyways, since both things are UI triggers for the same action: http://pastebin.com/2iLQ1jFt